# Error when connecting Firebase to Microsoft Power BI

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, powerbi

I am looking to connect Power BI to Google Firebase.

I've followed the below steps,

1. Get Data > Blank Query
2. Entered the below Query

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("url to firebase database")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source)
    in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

I've entered the url but it looks like its expecting a JSON output. How can I get a JSON output to include on Power BI to visualise data stored on Firebase?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For what I am looking in the error message in image, the problem in not connecting with Firebase, instead the problem is the query you are using, the variable source is getting the content of the page and that is why is giving you that error.

You can try this command that return the Json of the a collection with the values in it.

```
projects/{project_id}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/{document_path}/
```

The document path is the document that you want the information
And the databaseId if you don't know which is it, it is probably (default) you need to put the () in the url of the request

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/get) you can see how the Json is structured