# How to set up connection from Power BI to Google Firebase?

Tags: json, firebase, powerbi, powerquery

How to plug from Power BI to Google Firebase directly without Big Query? I have found a clue that it is possible however I am missing details. For reference check the first method suggested [here](https://hevodata.com/learn/firebase-power-bi-integration/) for connecting Power BI to Firebase. It is based on adding blank query in Power Query editor:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("url_to_your_firebase_database")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source)
    in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

However, I have no clue what exact the "url_to_your_firebase_database" should be. I do not even know if this method assumes a real time database or an ordinary one?

As a starting point to answer this question I suggest a path:
`Firebase > Gear icon (second row, left upper corner) > Project Settings`

What links or Web api keys should I get from there to create PBI connection?

Answer (score 0):

Its usually the url of your firebase app like: `https://appname.firebaseio.com`
The "`appname`" would be different based on the name of your firebase app

There's a similar discussion in below links, which you can refer to:

- [PowerBI forum](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Step-by-Step-process-for-loading-Firebase-Database-to-power-bi/td-p/221569)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66685338/error-when-connecting-firebase-to-microsoft-power-bi)
- [YouTube video showing Google Data Studio and Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sG9L93ZpRY4). The process will be similar for PowerBI too.

Comment: Thank you for taking part. That didn't help. The most promising was the last link. However I was not able to get it to work with PBI. I would like to know if a Real Time Database is a mandatory requirement for this method?